# Enthalpy of condensation

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

suppose we have one mole of an ideal gas undergoing a phase change at constant temperature. we know that enthalpy change is given by the formula $n\cdot Cp\cdot\delta(T)$. since there is no temperature change therefore enthalpy change should be zero,

- however it is not?where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> Where am I going wrong?

There is no liquid or solid that behaves like an [ideal gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas). So, there is no phase changing for any ideal gas. Ideal gas isn't a specific gas like oxygen, hydrogen, etc. It is an ideal behavior assumption. Liquid oxygen (for instance) isn't an ideal gas and so we cannot use the formula $\mathrm dh=C_p\mathrm dT$ because this formula has been obtained by ideal gas behavior assumption.

Comment: I think OP was asking about condensation from gaseous water to liquid.

Comment: @Dimitri There is no liquid with **ideal gas behavior**.

Answer (score 0):

During a phase change, the intermolecular forces change. This is because the average separation of the molecules changes, changing the average potential energy.
Since potential energy is a component of internal energy and it requires work or heat to change the internal energy, it follows that an enthalpy change must occur during a phase change.

Also for a phase change, the formula *nCpT=Q* no longer applies. The enthalpy change is given by mass (*m*) and latent heat of vaporisation (*L*)

*Q=mL*

Answer (score 0):

Enthalpy change of an ideal gas is given by the formula $dH = n c_p dT$ when it undergoes a change in temperature $dT$.

This formula is no longer valid when you undergo a phase transition : for a given quantity of water at a given temperature to vaporize requires a huge amount of enthalpy. See for example [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy_of_vaporization) wikipedia article.

Also, as it was noted in lucas' answer, an ideal gas cannot undergo a phase transition as you need molecular interaction to trigger it, which is absent in the ideal gas model.

Answer (score 0):

By definition $c_p = {(\partial h/\partial T)}_P$ is valid only for a "homogeneous phase of a substance of constant composition,...no change of phase..." [Sonntag and Van Wylen, Thermodynamics]  The same caveat applies to $c_V = {(\partial u/\partial T)}_V$. So the concept of specific heat does not apply to a change in phase.

Hope this helps.